# How to generate sequence but avoid numbering duplicates in groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sub_id': [101,101,101,102,102,103,104,104,105],
                   'test_id':['A1','A1','C1','A1','B1','D1','E1','A1','F1'],
                   'dummy':['hi','hello','how','are','you','am','fine','thank','you']})
```

I want each combination of `sub_id` and `test_id` to have a unique id (sequence number)

Please note that `one subject can have duplicate test_ids but dummy values will be different`.

Similarly, `multiple subjects can share the same test_ids` as shown in sample dataframe

So, I tried the below 2 approaches but they are incorrect.

```
df.groupby(['sub_id','test_id']).cumcount()+1  # incorrect
df['seq_id'] = df.index + 1 # incorrect
```

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

try via [`ngroup()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df['seq_id']=df.groupby(['sub_id','test_id'],sort=False).ngroup()+1
```

output of `df`:

```
   sub_id  test_id    dummy     seq_id
0   101     A1          hi          1
1   101     A1          hello       1
2   101     C1          how         2
3   102     A1          are         3
4   102     B1          you         4
5   103     D1          am          5
6   104     E1          fine        6
7   104     A1          thank       7
8   105     F1          you         8
```

Comment: Why sort = false? What diff does it make? Upvoted

Comment: @TheGreat If you don't write `sort=False` then you will not get seq_id of particular group in their correct sequence...ie the seq_id will be sorted in ascending order

Comment: Meaning, if we want the sequence to be in particular order (under each group), don't we have to write `sort=True`? Why does `sort=True` gives incorrect result and `sort=False` gives the correct result (in proper order)?. I did run the code and verify. Hence, asking you on why there is a opposite behavior?

Comment: @TheGreat by default in `groupby()` method `sort=True` and it give incorrect result because it sort the values in ascending order rather than the order in which the currently rows are in your dataframe and when we overwrite the sort parameter by `sort=False` then it will give the exact value according to the order of data in your dataframe