# how to reset index during `ngroups` to display group by column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sub_id': [101,101,101,102,102,103,104,104,105],
                   'test_id':['A1','A1','C1','A1','B1','D1','E1','A1','F1']})
```

I am numbering each of the unique groups of `sub_id` and `test_id` using below code (thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285984/how-to-generate-sequence-but-avoid-numbering-duplicates-in-groups))

```
df.groupby(['sub_id','test_id'],sort=False).ngroup()+1
```

but I want to display the group by columns as well during the output. So, I tried the below

```
df.set_index(['sub_id','test_id']).groupby(['sub_id','test_id'],sort=False).ngroup()+1
df.set_index(['sub_id','test_id']).groupby(['sub_id','test_id'],sort=False,as_index=False).ngroup()+1
```

Both the options display the groupby columns but am unable to `reset the index` to make it uniform

Currently the output looks like below which is incorrect

[image]

**but I want to reset the index (in the same line of code) and display it correctly**

Can help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap up code in brackets `()` then use `reset_index()`:

```
out=(df.set_index(['sub_id','test_id']).groupby(['sub_id','test_id'],sort=False).ngroup()+1).reset_index()
```

OR

Instead of `+1` use `add(1)` method then use `reset_index()`:

```
out=df.set_index(['sub_id','test_id']).groupby(['sub_id','test_id'],sort=False).ngroup().add(1).reset_index()
```